# Calling Javascript functions from C# Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, c#, unit-testing

I am working on a small project that will primarily be a C# library. I also want to create a JavaScript counterpart that is functionally equivalent. I would like to be able to test both from the same unit tests.

To be clear I am NOT going to be using this in a production environment where C# calls JS, or vice versa. I only want to blend C# and JavaScript in the context of the unit tests so I can verify and maintain cross-platform compatibility. Most examples I find show that this is possible within Blazor using JSRuntime, but I don't want to do this within a web application.

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

C# Method:

```
public class CsharpLibrary
{
    public static bool CheckLength(string str) {
        if (str.Length > 10)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

JavaScript Function:

```
function CheckLength(str) {
    if (str.length > 10)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Unit Test

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace CsharpJavascriptUnitTesting
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CheckLength_TooLong()
        {
            var str = "1234567890123456789";

            var isValid = CsharpLibrary.CheckLength(str);
            Assert.IsFalse(isValid);

            // TODO: is it possible to load the local Javascript file?
            // TODO: call JavaScript CheckLength(str);
            // TODO: assert that the value returned is also false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to unit test javascript, there are javascript libraries and runners for that.

Comment: You could use a .NET based JS interpreter like [Jurassic](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic).

Comment: You should be able to use Selenium webdriver and set the url to a data url which contains a html including your script. Than execute the sript and check the result.

Comment: @Taplar I know, but if possible I am trying to keep it to one master set of unit tests only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the recommendation in the [comment above from Collen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525709/calling-javascript-functions-from-c-sharp-unit-tests#comment115848136_65525709) I was able to accomplish this with the [Jurassic](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic) library.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckLength_TooLong()
{
    var str = "1234567890123456789";

    var isValid = CsharpLibrary.CheckLength(str);
    Assert.IsFalse(isValid);

    var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"..\..\JsLibrary.js");
    isValid = engine.CallGlobalFunction<bool>("CheckLength", str);
    Assert.IsFalse(isValid);
}
```

Comment: Even though this works I am not going to accept this as the answer just yet. The Jurassic library doesn't appear to have much activity in recent months (or years), and the Ecmascript 6 status table shows that it is still a work-in-progress. So I am going to leave this question open in hopes of finding a cleaner way to achieve this with functionality native to .NET